# Google ignores canonical and selects alt but still shows canonical

Tags: seo, google, search-engine-indexing, hreflang

This is kind of complicated scenario.

I have this URL: 
www.example.com/this-is-page-A

Which has correctly implemented canonical and hreflang directives.

On Google console i can see Google decided to change the canonical version i declared with one of the hreflang, so now my canonical link on Google view is:
www.row.example.com/this-is-page-A

Google decided to select the subdomain i use for the rest of the world and ignore my UK domain.

The funny part is if you search on Google: site:www.example.com/this-is-page-A
nothing comes up but if you search site:www.row.example.com/this-is-page-A 
the row subdomain comes up, now if you search the exact title of the page this is the URL that comes up: www.example.com/this-is-page-A

Hopefully my process explanation is clear, any idea how to solve this?

Comment: Where are you searching from?   It might make a difference between UK and US or AU.

Comment: It would be good to add examples of your canonical and hreflangs to your question.   It is very easy to mess them up.   Each language (including ROW) should have its own canonical.  It sounds like that may not be the case here.

Comment: The canonical and hreflang are correctly implemented on both URLs, Google is ignoring them for some reason and is doing this tricky thing.